# Visual Studio Installation Project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, installation

When creating a set-up project in Visual Studio 2008, I am trying to create an MSI.  I have a standalone installation project - that is, I don’t have a main project to install, I just want to ship some random files.

Configuration properties / build shows that it should create debug/myproj.msi.  However, if I do a build of either the solution or the project, I only get an exe.

Do I need to compile this in a certain way to force it to create an MSI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To build an installer package you must right click on the project and select "Build".  Or modify the solution settings to include a build of the installer.

By default installers are NOT built on every build, this is for performance reasons.